# Renaming or copying files and folder using NERDTree on Vim. Is it possible?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I checked the documentation and I couldn't find a way o renaming or copying files and folder using NERDTree. Is it possible?

Comment: type :h NERDTree in vim. you will get almost any help directly from vim. saves time :)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Press `m` on the node you want to then select `(m)ove the current node`. Moving is the same as renaming.

```
NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated
==========================================================
> (a)dd a childnode
  (m)ove the curent node
  (d)elete the curent node
  (c)copy the current node
```

Comment: Great answer saved my life! Is there a way to disable the confirm question when delete a file by using 'm + d', It really tedious to confirm, and it need to confirm twice. I just want it no prompt at all. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: You can disable the confirm prompt by changing confirmed = 0 to confirmed = 1 in nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt, the latest version has it:

> 2.3. The NERD tree menu                                         *NERDTreeMenu*   The NERD tree has a menu that can be programmed via the an
>   API (see |NERDTreeMenuAPI|). The idea
>   is to simulate the "right click" menus
>   that most file explorers have.   The
>   script comes with two default menu
>   plugins: exec_menuitem.vim and
>   fs_menu.vim. fs_menu.vim adds some
>   basic filesystem operations to the
>   menu for
>   creating/deleting/moving/copying files
>   and dirs. exec_menuitem.vim provides a
>   menu item to execute executable files.

Comment: I checked it. But how do I make the menu appear?

Comment: If you had installed it properly, you should have a nerdtree_plugin folder in your Vim runtime directory. There should resist exec_menuitem.vim and fs_menu.vim. Now you should only start a graphical Vim instance & NerdTree.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using gVim and Nerdtree with "m" I open a windows but renaming isn't there I right click on nodes and renaming is not there either (I do have those 2 files).